# Is render 'contribute' synonymous with render :action => 'contribute'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

Do these two forms of 'render' have the same effect?

```
render 'contribute'
render :action => 'contribute'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Yes, they are the same.
However, sometimes passing a string will result in a call to `render :file` or `render :template`.

[Here's the API docs for the render function](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000633)

If we scroll down and click 'Show Source' we can see what it's doing under the hood.

Note the block starting at line 872:

```
872:         elsif options.is_a?(String) || options.is_a?(Symbol)
873:           case options.to_s.index('/')
874:           when 0
875:             extra_options[:file] = options
876:           when nil
877:             extra_options[:action] = options
878:           else
879:             extra_options[:template] = options
880:           end
```

By looking at this code, we can determine that it is trying to be smart.

- If the string starts with a `/`, (the `when 0` case) then it will call `render :file`
- If the string doesn't contain a `/` at all, (the `when nil` case) then it will call `render :action`
- If the string contains a `/` somewhere in the middle or end of the string (then `else` case), then it will call `render :template`

Hope this answers your question satisfactorily :-)

Comment: Now that's an answer. Thanks.